# Django Import Export, Filter ForeignKey objects connected to users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm building an import excel files system for every leads whit an import-export library. On the Website, each user must be able to import his leads and make sure that they are viewed only by him. In all other cases, I filtered the "organisation" field linked to a UserProfile model through the views.py. But now I don't know how to filter the field organisation for a specific user. At the moment I can import the excel files from the template but leave the organisation field blank. Help me please I'm desperate

Models.py

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cognome = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    luogo=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, choices=region_list)
    città=models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    description = models.TextField()  
    agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", related_name="leads", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    chance=models.ForeignKey("Chance",related_name="chance", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="profile_pictures/")
    converted_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)

    objects = LeadManager()
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.nome} {self.cognome}"
   
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_organisor = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)


 class UserProfile(models.Model):
     
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Views.py

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Lead_resource = LeadResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        newdoc = request.FILES['myfile']
        

        imported_data = dataset.load(newdoc.read(),format='xlsx')
        #print(imported_data)
        for data in imported_data:
            value = Lead(
                data[0],
                data[2],#nome
                data[3],#cognome
                data[5],#luogo
                data[7],#città
                data[8],#email
                data[9],#numero telefono
                data[11],#desc 
                )
            value.save()
    
        
        result = Lead_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

        if not result.has_errors():
            Lead_resource.import_data(dataset,dry_run=False)  # Actually import now

    return render(request, 'input.html')
```

Resources.py

```
class LeadResource(resources.ModelResource):

nome = fields.Field(attribute='nome', column_name='nome')
luogo = fields.Field(attribute='luogo', column_name='regione')

class Meta:
    model = Lead
    report_skipped=True
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Lead)
class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
  readonly_fields = ('date_added',)
```

Comment: Technically the `UserProfile` has a foreign key to the user Model. Something like this should work:  `Lead.objects.filter(organization__user=user)` (assuming that the user object is stored in the user variable).

Comment: @Mattia thanks for your answer! I have seen your answer a little late. I have already tried several times to use "objects.filter" but unfortunately saving the excel data remains without an organization. Where would you use the "objects.filter"?